# Hibernate inserta siempre valor nulo en foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Estoy desarrollando un servicio con java e hibernate. Tengo en el modelo la siguiente clase:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Cliente.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Cliente c")
public class Cliente implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String dni;

private int edad;

private String nombre;

private String profesion;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Estado
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_estado")
private Estado estado;

public Cliente() {
}

public String getDni() {
    return this.dni;
}

public void setDni(String dni) {
    this.dni = dni;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return this.edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getProfesion() {
    return this.profesion;
}

public void setProfesion(String profesion) {
    this.profesion = profesion;
}

public Estado getEstado() {
    return this.estado;
}

public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}
```

}
Esta clase mapea la siguiente tabla en bbdd mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cliente` (
`dni` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`edad` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`profesion` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_estado` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`dni`),
KEY `FK_cliente_pais` (`id_estado`) USING BTREE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_cliente_estado` FOREIGN KEY (`id_estado`) REFERENCES `estado` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

El problema que tengo es el siguiente: cuando intento hacer una inserción de un cliente haciendo uso de hibernate, siempre me insertar valor null en el campo id_estado. El resto de campos los insertar bien, pero siempre mete nulo en el campo que es clave ajena. Este es el código java de la inserción:

```
SessionFactory factory = getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Cliente c = new Cliente();
        c.setDni(dni);
        c.setNombre(nombre);
        c.setEdad(edad);
        c.setProfesion(profesion);
        c.setEstado(session.find(Estado.class, id_estado));
        session.save(c);
        
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        
        result = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    
    
    session.close();
    factory.close();
    return result;
```

¿Alguien sabe que está pasando?

Gracias por adelantado, y un saludo

Comment: Si lo pone siempre en `null` imagino que te dé error al tratar de insertar, no? Por otra parte, `session.find(Estado.class, id_estado)` qué devuelve?

Comment: Ya he encontrado la solución. Faltaba añadir el campo id_estado en el fichero de configuración de hibernate, el relacionado con la tabla Cliente. Al añadir lo siguiente: <many-to-one name="estado"><column name="id_estado"/></many-to-one> ha funcionado perfectamente.